# Can I install and run MS office on alternate drive?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, installation, microsoft-office

I have recently installed a 120GB SSD and it is now my c: drive. I am finding that some programs can be run from an alternate drive (Just moving an icon to the desk top that targets to other drive for location) that they were originaly insalled on and others won't.

One in particular is MS Office. I want to access it and manage my word and excel stuff but I don't want to load the program on my limited space drive when I have a 1.5 TB HHD hooked up. If I go to the folder it is stored on and try to open the Word.exe, I get a message

> The operating system is not presently configured to run this
>   application

So can I do this? Run Office from my 1.5 TB drive vs. loading it onto the 120GB SSD?

> Edit: this is Office 2007 Home and Student

Comment: How did word.exe get into its current location? Sounds like you manually copied it there. That won't work. You need to run the installer and specify the alternative drive as the installation location.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch - I just went into the "old" drive where is was installed and clicked the application icon. If I were to boot to the old drive, I can access any Office item I like with no problem.

Comment: So you have more than one Windows install? You have to run Office from the Windows you installed it from.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch - yes. I never removed the win 7 from the "old" drive that is the 1.5 TB.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install office again on your current windows installation.
While installing, provide alternate installation path on your 1.5TB HDD(Other that the one which currently has word.exe, in order to avoid any conflicts of files).

Comment: For those who need the installer: 

https://products.office.com/en-us/get-office-oem-download-page

Answer (score 1):

You could try uninstalling and reinstalling Word, configuring it to be run from the second drive (ex. `D:\Program Files`)

Comment: I Put the version in my question. 2007 Home and student.